# Access violation reading location 0xc3618000

Tags: c++, dll, crash, access-violation

I am working on a project about IR Tracking and I am using FreeTrack (www.free-track.net) software for it. FreeTrack offers a sdk folder with their download with C, Matlab and delphi code which can be used to interface the data from FreeTrack to your own writing program in one of these languages.

I started off with Matlab, but when matlab gave a problem, I went on to C++ in Mvisual. This also gives a problem, which seems like the same in Matlab.

Here is the thing: 
When i want to read data from a DLL of the freetrack client, I use:

```
//declare imported function pointers
importGetData getData;
getData = (importGetData)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTGetData");

if (getData(pData))
printf("Yaw: %f\n", data.yaw);
```

First time it works, but the data is 0. Second time it does it, Mvisual gives the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0xc3618000 in FreeTrack.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation
reading location 0xc3618000.
```

getData has the adres 0xc3618000.

This only happens when FreeTrack is running. When it isnt, No data is returned from getData.

Any idea's what this can be?

Original code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct
{
    float yaw;
    float pitch;
    float roll;
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    int dataID;
}FreeTrackData;

// DLL function signatures
// These match those given in FTTypes.pas
// WINAPI is macro for __stdcall defined somewhere in the depths of windows.h
typedef bool (WINAPI *importGetData)(FreeTrackData * data);
typedef char *(WINAPI *importGetDllVersion)(void);
typedef void (WINAPI *importReportID)(int name);
typedef char *(WINAPI *importProvider)(void);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        /*while(1){
        printf("hello");
        }*/
        //declare imported function pointers
        importGetData getData;
        importGetDllVersion getDllVersion;
        importReportID  reportID;
        importProvider provider;

        // create variables for exchanging data with the dll
        FreeTrackData data;
        FreeTrackData *pData;
        pData = &data;
        char *pDllVersion;
        int name = 453;
        char *pProvider;

        //while(1){};
        // Load DLL file
        HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary("FreeTrackClient.dll");
        if (hinstLib == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to load DLL\n");
                //return 1;
                while(1){};
        }
        else
        {
            printf("dll loaded\n");
        }
        //while(1){};
        // Get function pointers
        getData = (importGetData)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTGetData");
        getDllVersion = (importGetDllVersion)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTGetDllVersion");
        //reportID = (importReportID)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTReportID");
        reportID = (importReportID)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTReportName");
        provider = (importProvider)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "FTProvider");

        // Check they are valid
        if (getData == NULL) {
                printf("ERROR: unable to find 'FTGetData' function\n");
               FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                //return 1;
        }
        if (getDllVersion == NULL){
                printf("ERROR: unable to find 'FTGetDllVersion' function\n");
               FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                //return 1;
        }
        if (reportID == NULL){
                printf("ERROR: unable to find 'FTReportID' function\n");
               FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                //return 1;
        }
        if (reportID == NULL){
                printf("ERROR: unable to find 'FTProvider' function\n");
               FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
                //return 1;
        }

        //  Print the address of each function
        printf("FTGetData is at address: 0x%x\n",getData);
        printf("FTGetDllVersion is at address: 0x%x\n",getDllVersion);
        printf("FTReportID is at address: 0x%x\n",reportID);
        printf("FTProvider is at address: 0x%x\n",provider);

        //  Call each function and display result
        pDllVersion = getDllVersion();
        printf("Dll Version: %s\n", pDllVersion);

        pProvider = provider();
        printf("Provider: %s\n", pProvider);

        reportID(name); //not sure what this does - I guess it tells the dll that I am using it.

        system("pause"); //wait till keyboard is pressed before entering main loop
        while( kbhit() != 1)
        {
            //system("cls"); //clear screen
            if (getData(pData))
            {
                printf("Provider: %s\n", pProvider);
                printf("Record ID: %d\n" , data.dataID);
                printf("Yaw: %5.2f\n" , data.yaw );
                printf("Pitch: %5.2f\n" , data.pitch );
                printf("Roll: %5.2f\n" , data.roll );
                printf("X: %5.2f\n" , data.x );
                printf("Y: %5.2f\n" , data.y );
                printf("Z: %5.2f\n" , data.z );
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Nothing returned from getData\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        // Unload DLL file
        FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: typedef struct { float yaw; float pitch; float roll; float x; float y; float z; int dataID; }FreeTrackData;

FreeTrackData data;
FreeTrackData *pData;

Comment: I do not think i has to do with the printing, because when I put a break point at "if 9getData(pdata))" and i step into/over it, then the problem occurs

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you comment out the call to `reportID`?

Comment: i dont see any difference at first glance

Answer (score 0):

You told `printf` that `yaw` was a C-style string, but it's a float!

Comment: Yea that a mistake, it should be %f

Comment: Then probably the mistake is that you forgot to initialize `pData` with something like `pData=&data;`. So you passed `getData` the value of an uninitialized variable.

Comment: I do that just after the creating of data and *pdata

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be caused by the structure definition of FreeTrackData.
I found an updated one from [this post](http://www.free-track.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=1666), and hope that would help.